# Pasar array entre páginas en Flutter

Tags: flutter

Tengo 3 'pantallas' en mi app.  En la primera obtengo los datos por medio de campos TextFormField.  Estos datos son enviados a la segunda utilizando algo como

```
              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                    new SegundaPagina(
                      value: Data(
                              primero: _primerCampo.text,
                              segundo: _segundoCampo.text,
                              tercero: __tercerCampo.text,
                      )
                    ),
              );
```

Estos datos son recibidos en la segunda página a través de la respectiva clase, algo como:

```
class SegundaPagina extends StatefulWidget {
  final Data value;

  SegundaPagina({Key key, this.value}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SegundaPaginaState createState() => _SegundaPaginaState();
}
```

Y algo más de código para leer y utilizar cada campo, a través de instrucciones como:

```
          'PRIMERO : ${widget.value.primero}',
```

Hasta acá no hay problemas, todo funciona.  El 'problema' surge de la necesidad de enviar los datos generados en la primera página (en éste caso son 3, pero pueden ser muchos más) a la tercera, cuarta páginas, etc., sin necesidad de tener que describir campo por campo para poderlos utilizar.  Requiero algo similar a enviar una caja de herramientas de un domicilio a otro, sin tener que describir una por una para poderlas utilizar.

¿Es posible? Agradezco sus sugerencias.  Soy nuevo en Flutter, y en StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

Ya que no pones el contenido de tu clase `Data` voy a deducirla.

```dart
class Data {

String primero;
String segundo;
String tercero;

//constructor aquí...

}
```

Podrías empezar reemplazando esos 3 atributos por un array de `String`, así:

```dart
class Data {

List<String> valores = [];


//constructor aquí...
}
```

Y al momento de crear la clase lo harías así:

```dart
 builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                    new SegundaPagina(
                      value: Data(
                              valores: [_primerCampo.text,
                               _segundoCampo.text,
                               _tercerCampo.text],
                      )
                    ),
              );
```

Lo usarías de la siguiente forma:

```dart
'PRIMERO : ${widget.value.valores[0]}'
'SEGUNDO : ${widget.value.valores[1]}'
'TERCERO : ${widget.value.valores[2]}'
```

Obviamente que puedes usar un bucle para recorrer y pintar esos valores

Comment: @diegodeveloper gracias por responder.  Pero OK, ya tengo en el array "valores" los campos A,ByC, en mi 'segunda pantalla'.  Ahora, cómo hago para enviar todo el array de una vez a la tercera pantalla, sin necesidad de detallar cada uno de los valores del array?  Agradezco tu colaboración

Comment: solo envía `widget.value` a la siguiente pantalla, value tiene el array de valores dentro

Comment: revisa mi respuesta, te puse con detalle como agregas y como  pasas los valores, si te sirvió la marcas como resuelta.
Te recomiendo que leas esta guía : https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour

Comment: Aún no resulta; revisaré con cuidado todo lo indicado, enseguida tus likes.  Gracias por tus indicaciones!